# Is this a bug in mathematica for integrals of multiple error functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I'm scratching my head over the the following result in Mathematica (v11.3)

I'm considering the function

```
B = Erfc[x] Exp[-x^2/2] + Sqrt[2] Erfc[x/Sqrt[2]] Exp[-x^2]
```

Wich is smooth near $x=0$

For instance `Plot[B, {x, -1, 1}]` gives

[image: B(x)]

They function is also holomporphic and thus analytically continuable into the complex plane such that `Plot3D[Abs[B /. x -> (xp + I y)], {xp, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]` gives

[image]

But if i integrate it using

```
 BI = Integrate[B, {x, a, \[Infinity]}]
```

I get the function

```
 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] + Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] Erf[a] (-1 + Erf[a/Sqrt[2]]) +  1/2 a ExpIntegralE[1/2, a^2/2]
```

which has a discontinuity at $a=0$?!
See e.g. `Plot[BI, {a, -1, 1}]`

[image]

This should not be able to happen with the integral of a smooth function, right?

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

B = Erfc[x] Exp[-x^2/2] + Sqrt[2] Erfc[x/Sqrt[2]] Exp[-x^2];
```

If you explicitly state that `a` is a real value, Mathematica will tell you that the result is conditional on `a > 0`

```
BI = Assuming[Element[a, Reals], Integrate[B, {x, a, ∞}]]

(* ConditionalExpression[
 1/2 (Sqrt[2 π] Erf[a] (-1 + Erf[a/Sqrt[2]]) + 
    a ExpIntegralE[1/2, a^2/2]), a > 0] *)
```

With the assumption `a > 0` the integral simplifies

```
Assuming[a > 0, FullSimplify[BI]]

(* Sqrt[π/2] Erfc[a] Erfc[a/Sqrt[2]] *)
```

Or more directly,

```
BI2 = Assuming[a > 0, Integrate[B, {x, a, ∞}]]

(* Sqrt[π/2] Erfc[a] Erfc[a/Sqrt[2]] *)
```

The same result is returned for `a <= 0`

```
Assuming[a <= 0, Integrate[B, {x, a, ∞}]] == BI2

(* True *)
```

Consequently, `BI2` is the integral for all real `a`

```
Plot[BI2, {a, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: So as always, it falls back on always telling mathematics everything.

Comment: Mathematica generally assumes that all variables are complex. If that is not the case, you need to tell Mathematica what **your** assumptions are.

Comment: I consider this behavior to be a bug. Even assuming $a$ is complex, the result for real $a$ should be continuous. What you have found is just a workaround.

Comment: @BobHanlon But the function is holomorphic, with no branch curt near $x=0$, I don't se why a step function should show up here....

Comment: To find the integral, the algorithm either generalized the form of the integrand or otherwise transformed the integrand in one or more ways to find a pattern for which it had a rule. The conditional result given using the assumption `Element[a, Reals]` indicates that at least one of these transformations is valid only when `a > 0`. Since the result is the integral only when `a > 0`, how it behaves outside of this constraint is immaterial. However, then using this constraint as an assumption to simplify the result gave a result which is valid more generally for all real `a`.

Comment: @MikaelFremling No one has mentioned it, so perhaps it's not obvious, that the branch-cut problem is not with the integrand but with the formula for the integral, specifically with the exponential integral: `Series[a ExpIntegralE[1/2, a^2/2], {a, 0, 0}]`.  This arises in the antiderivative `Integrate[E^(-(x^2/2)) Erfc[x], x]`, even though is it expressible in terms of the holomorph `Erf[]`: Try `Simplify[% // FunctionExpand, x > 0]` on the result, which seems to produce a valid antiderivative.  It might also perform the transformation $x\mapsto ax$, which makes $a=0$ singular.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank for the long, explanation. It also highlights why this is a bug if Mathematica. At no point did is specify that $a>0$, yet I get and expression that is only valid in that regime. I admit that it was implicit that $a$ was real, but that should not be important here since the function I'm integrating is holomorphic.

Comment: @MichaelE2 indeed there is no brach-cut problem with the integrand. Indeed the whole problem lies in the answer matheamtica is giving me. I get an answer that has a branch-cut and thus is only valid when $a>$, even though an answer for a general $a$ was asked. The desired behavior here is to either put in a conditional that $a>0$ is a requirement, is answer nothing at all. Thus this is a bug.